# page redirect , before ajax call success

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, firefox

I'm using jquery 1.7.2 for some ajax call onloud of an aspx page.
ajax calls webservice methods .
if user push refresh button or click on some menu to redirect to another page when ajax calls still in progress and not success yet, an error shown in firebug console that not make sense.
what can i do to kill ajax pending requests when user try to leave the page?

Comment: surely you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this 
for instance it your ajax calling function

```
var call = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mywebservice.aspx",
    data: "some data you are passing ",
    success: function(msg){
      // do stuff on sucess
    }
});
```

and the you can call this to kill the process.

```
call.abort()
```

Comment: Thanks , but when should i call abort if i wanna kill process before page unload ?

Comment: whenever you redirect the page you must have a button or a link so as you click the link you should execute abort

Comment: my problem is when user push browser refresh button.

Comment: you want to stop abort() only when refreshed not load

Comment: I want to kill alive ajax calls if user not wait for success and leave the page in one of this ways : refresh the page , click on some menu to redirect to another page.

Comment: on the refresh you might check if the ajax content in ad div is fully loaded if not than kill it and for menu click just kill the call when it cliked