# Page redirect before ajax success

Tags: ajax, redirect

In my system, When I click into a button, 1st ajax call order function in localhost, 2nd ajax call API fucntion to a other host.

The problem is the 1st process complete before the 2nd process, and it call redirect function while the 2nd process is running, so firefox browser alert error (uncaught exception: out of memory). How I solve the problem?

Comment: Try to use sleep or wait of threads if the API call is occurring multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this way, maybe only this way solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [page redirect , before ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630380/page-redirect-before-ajax-call-success)